# RecyclerView list gone when scrolling down

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a multiple view in my `recyclerview`, but when i scroll it the data is gone and the list form is messy and it don't stop even if the data was finished. so i don't know what is going on. but i think there is problem in my adapter but i have no idea what it is.

**My Activity**

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_last, container, false)
        rootView.recyclerView_main.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        fetchJson()
        return rootView

    }

    fun fetchJson(){
        val url = "https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/eventspastleague.php?id=4328"
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback, okhttp3.Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: okhttp3.Call?, response: okhttp3.Response?) {
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                println(body)

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val teamFeed = gson.fromJson(body, TeamFeed::class.java)

                runOnUiThread {
                    recyclerView_main.adapter = MainAdapter(teamFeed)
                    recyclerView_main.recycledViewPool.setMaxRecycledViews(0, 0)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: okhttp3.Call?, e: IOException) {
                println("failed")
            }

        })
    }

    class TeamFeed(val events: List<Results>)
    class Results(val strHomeTeam: String, val strAwayTeam: String, val intHomeScore: String, val intAwayScore: String, val dateEvent: String)
```

**My Adapter**

```
class MainAdapter(val teamFeed: LastActivity.TeamFeed) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

    return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,
            parent, false))
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return teamFeed.events.count()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val team = teamFeed.events.get(position)
    holder.itemView.home_team?.text = team.strHomeTeam
    holder.itemView.away_team?.text = team.strAwayTeam
    holder.itemView.home_score?.text = team.intHomeScore
    holder.itemView.away_score?.text = team.intAwayScore
    holder.itemView.tanggal?.text = team.dateEvent

}
class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

if there is someone have an idea how to solve it please help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: RecyclerView recycles cells when it is scrolled, can you put a breakpoint on your onBindViewHolder when scrolling to see if `team` is being set, or has any value at all?

Comment: yes it has a value i get it from json. i'll upload the main code

Comment: Why do you call `setMaxRecycledViews()`?

Comment: i was looking for the answer and there is someone that said it could be the answer but it didn't even work